# Use binary string returned from backend to create Object URL for video src

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html5-video

I am trying to use binary video data returned from my fastAPI backend and load it into a video element.  The backend correctly sends video as I can curl the endpoint and save file and it plays fine on my laptop.

I am using React+Typescript for the frontend, the binary video data is fetched in a loader for a React Router route, here is my code

```
### loader for route ###
import axios from "axios"

export const loader = async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    const response = await axios.get(
        import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + 'video/avatar.mp4',
        {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'responseType': 'video/mp4',
            }
        } 
    )
    const blob = new Blob([response.data])
    const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    return videoURL
}
```

```
### route component ###
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"

const VideoListContainer = () => {
    const videoURL = useLoaderData() as string

    return (
        <div>
            <video controls>
                <source src={videoURL} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
    )
}

export default VideoListContainer
```

Mozilla outputs error
`Media resource blob:http://localhost:5173/f24a119a-f83a-4062-8715-5b0386fc6e22 could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006) Details: static MP4Metadata::ResultAndByteBuffer mozilla::MP4Metadata::Metadata(mozilla::ByteStream *): Cannot parse metadata`
Chrome outputs no error at all, but doesn't load

Just want to get video loaded in  element before I get into the nitty gritty stuff.  Something must be going on with the Blob I'm moving around, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: If still not solved, see if using `fetch` helps to get a byte/buffer Array returned, I suspect Axios is the weak link here. It only loads bytes in a web page projects (not in native projects, even when testing their code in a browser, etc), which as you say yours is a browser-based webpage therefore it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Try `const videoURL = useLoaderData()` without the `as string` part. 
The pointer from **createObjectURL** goes to a bytes **array**, not to a text **string**.

**(2)** Try setting up your Blob this way:

```
const blob = new Blob( new Uint8Array( response.data ) )
//const blob = new Blob( [ Uint8Array.from( response.data ) ] ) //# alt method if above fails
const videoURL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob)
return videoURL
```

**(3)** I don't use ReactJS but you need to get to a point where you can set the video tag's **source** by code.

For example:

- Give your video tag an ID, to access it later in other functions.
- Instead of returning a URL, set here the video tag's src *eg:* `myVid.src = videoURL`.
- Also need to load/play it with: `myVid.load();` and `myVid.play();`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252601/discussion-on-answer-by-vc-one-use-binary-string-returned-from-backend-to-create); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.